# Jakson Error. Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: java, json, jackson

Есть json

```
{
    "settings": {
        "NUMBER": 970,
        "LIST": [{
            "name": "Name",
            "minimum": 56.0,
            "maximum": 180.0
        }]
    }
}
```

Есть dto к этому json-у

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Dto {

    private int number;

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    @JsonProperty("settings")
    private void obtainStoreNumber(Map<String, String> settings) {
        this.number = Integer.parseInt(settings.get("NUMBER"));
    }
}
```

При попытке смапить жсон в дто выбрасывается ошибка Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_ARRAY token

Что я делаю не так ?

Comment: Вы объявили Map<String, String>, тогда как у вас там массив. Наверное, получится только что-то такое: Map<String, Object>, хотя это и не имеет особого смысла. По идее вам надо создать 2 класса - один с полем `Settings setting` и один с полем `NUMBER NUMBER`.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо. так и оказалось